# v-usb, zener diodes and circuit

Tags: usb, diodes, attiny, zener

I've toying with V-USB for a few days and got a circuit working in a breadboard with a Attiny85 and 3.6 Zener diodes.

However, when I tried to get it done in a stripboard, it doesn't work.

Assuming the soldering is correct, the only think that can be a problem is a modification I did to make it easier to solder.

Is this:

[image]

equivalent to this?

[image: P9AWj]

Can this modification be the problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although USB uses 5V as power supply, both datalines are rated at

- min. 2.8V - max. 3.6V for HIGH
- min. 0.0V - max. 0.3V for LOW

This means that the inputs on host side, your PC/hub/..., must not be driven higher than 3V6. Your controller (AVR) on the other hand, when fed from 5V, attempt to drive these pins up to 5V causing the host side input circuitry (on your PC) to fail.

There are two scenarios to solve this situation:

1. You lower power supply for the AVR to 3.6V. The controller can no longer drive the data lines too high to damage input circuitry on PC (host).
2. (This is in your schematics) You power the AVR from 5V, but clip the voltages on its outputs with a zener to the max 3.6V. In this case the resistors definitely go between AVR and zener, otherwise you overdrive the AVR outputs.

Answer (score 1):

Another potential problem with your relocated 68 ohm resistors is that when the USB signal is being driven from the X1 side of your diagram the 68 ohm and the 1.5K ohm resistor form a voltage divider which results in a slightly elevated low level of the signal making it out the location on the right side of the diagram. This loss of signal amplitude may or may not be a problem. Enough said. The circuits are NOT equivalent.